# Mysql - Fetch data from EXISTS (SELECT..) statement aswell

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that returns `user_name` and `sess_start` from `sess_active` table if `user_name` exists in `sess_active_tmp` table.

Query below for above is working as inteded, but I also would like to retrieve data from `sess_active_tmp` table aswell. Since I execute another `SELECT` statement in `EXISTS` part, shouldn't I be able to retrieve data of this statement aswell?

Working query:

```
SELECT sess_main.user_name, 
       sess_main.sess_start 
FROM   sess_active AS sess_main 
WHERE  ( sess_main.user_name = 'testuser' 
         AND sess_main.sess_stop IS NULL ) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT user_name 
                   FROM   sess_active_tmp AS sess_temp 
                   WHERE  sess_temp.user_name = 'testuser' 
                          AND sess_temp.sess_start = 
                              sess_main.sess_start 
                          AND sess_temp.sess_stop IS NULL)
```

Query I am trying to get it work;

```
SELECT sess_main.user_name, 
       sess_main.sess_start,
       sess_temp.upload_byte,
       sess_temp.download_byte,
FROM   sess_active AS sess_main 
WHERE  ( sess_main.user_name = 'testuser' 
         AND sess_main.sess_stop IS NULL ) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT user_name 
                   FROM   sess_active_tmp AS sess_temp 
                   WHERE  sess_temp.user_name = 'testuser' 
                          AND sess_temp.sess_start = 
                              sess_main.sess_start 
                          AND sess_temp.sess_stop IS NULL)
```

I also added `sess_temp.upload_byte, sess_temp.download_byte` to `sess_temp` select statement but it also doesn't work.

Is it only achievable with `JOIN` and if yes would it decrease performance? since this query will run like 2-3k times(users) every 2 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Query below does what I want to achieve but I have performance concerns, is it the best way to achieve what I want to do?

```
SELECT sess_main.user_name, 
       sess_main.sess_start, 
       sess_temp.upload_byte, 
       sess_temp.download, 
FROM   sess_active AS sess_main 
       INNER JOIN sess_active_tmp sess_temp 
               ON ( sess_temp.user_name = sess_main.user_name 
                    AND sess_temp.sess_start = sess_main.sess_start 
                    AND sess_temp.sess_stop IS NULL ) 
WHERE  ( sess_main.user_name = 'testuser' 
         AND sess_main.sess_stop IS NULL ) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT user_name 
                   FROM   sess_active_tmp AS sess_temp 
                   WHERE  sess_temp.user_name = 'testuser' 
                          AND sess_temp.sess_start = sess_main.sess_start 
                          AND sess_temp.sess_stop IS NULL)
```

Comment: Are you sure your last query works, you are referencing a table(or view) btk_main which isn't invoked?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, as well as the above, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for same.

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry that was my test query, so fixed the typo.

Comment: You cannot access the table of a correlated subquery from the main query. It is just the nature of the beast. A join would be a better choice for this query, and would perform a lot better as well.